# Xcode Unit Testing - Accessing Resources from the application's bundle?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, unit-testing, xcode, bundle

I'm running into an issue and I wanted to confirm that I'm doing things the correct way.

I can test simple things with my SenTestingKit tests, and that works okay.  I've set up a Unit Test Bundle and set it as a dependency on the main application target.  It successfully runs all tests whenever I press cmd+B.

Here's where I'm running into issues.  I have some XML files that I need to load from the resources folder as part of the application.  Being a good unit tester, I want to write unit tests around this to make sure that they are loading properly.

So I have some code that looks like this:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] 
    pathForResource:@"foo" ofType:@"xml"];
```

This works when the application runs, but during a unit test, `mainBundle` points to the wrong bundle, so this line of code returns nil.

So I changed it up to utilize a known class like this:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle bundleForClass:[Config class]] 
    pathForResource:@"foo" ofType:@"xml"];
```

This doesn't work either, because in order for the test to even compile code like this, it `Config` needs to be part of the Unit Test Target.  If I add that, then the bundle for that class becomes the Unit Test bundle.  (Ugh!)

Am I approaching this the wrong way?

Comment: Try building it and then run the tests.  I saw an iTunes U video on this and they said that if the test target wasn't set up properly that it would test on the last build when run instead of building then running tests.

Have you checked to make sure that is not the case?

Comment: Try building the unit test project?  Part of the unit test bundle is to run the scripts, so I have it set up as a dependency of my application's target.  CMD+B should always run tests.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

While trying to reproduce your problem it hit me: Have you tried just adding your resources to your test bundle? Would that cause any problems for you? I did exactly that, and it worked great for me. For example:

Code:

```
- (void)testBundleLoading {
  NSLog(@"Main Bundle Path: %@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]);

  for (NSBundle *bundle in [NSBundle allBundles]) {
    NSLog(@"%@: %@", [bundle bundleIdentifier], 
                     [bundle pathForResource:@"fire" ofType:@"png"]);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
2010-05-05 14:31:05.961 otest[16970:903] Main Bundle Path: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.1.3.sdk/Developer/usr/bin
2010-05-05 14:31:05.962 otest[16970:903] (null): (null)
2010-05-05 14:31:05.963 otest[16970:903] com.freetimestudios.KayakKingTests: /Volumes/FreeTime/KayakKing/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/KayakKingTests.octest/fire.png
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem with Xcode 4 and my problem was that I had an old Xcode 3 project and somehow the info plist for the test target had gone missing. I added a new UnitTests-Info.plist to the project and I was suddenly able to retrieve resources again.